# Firebase query for bi-directional link

Tags: firebase

I'm designing a chat app much like Facebook Messenger. My two current root nodes are `chats` and `users`. A user has an associated list of chats `users/user/chats`, and the chats are added by autoID in the `chats` node `chats/a151jl1j6`. That node stores information such as a list of the messages, time of the last message, if someone is typing, etc.

What I'm struggling with is where to make the definition of which two users are in the chat. Originally, I put a reference to the other user as the value of the chatId key in the `users/user/chats` node, but I thought that was a bad idea incase I ever wanted group chats.

What seems more logical is to have a `chats/chat/members` node in which I define `userId: true, user2id: true`. My issue with this is how to efficiently query it. For example, if the user is going to create a new chat with a user, we want to check if a chat already exists between them. I'm not sure how to do the query of "Find chat where members contains `currentUserId` and `friendUserId`" or if this is an efficient denormalized way of doing things.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the idea of having ids in the format `id1---||---id2` definitely gets the job done, it may not scale if you expect to have large groups and you have to account for `id2---||---id1` comparisons which also gets more complicated when you have more people in a conversation. You should go with that if you don't need to worry about large groups.

I'd actually go with using the autoId `chats/a151jl1j6` since you get it for free. The recommended way to structure the data is to make the autoId the key in the other nodes with related child objects. So `chats/a151jl1j6` would contain the conversation metadata, `members/a151jl1j6` would contain the members in that conversation, `messages/a151jl1j6` would contain the messages and so on.

```json
"chats":{
    "a151jl1j6":{}}

"members":{
    "a151jl1j6":{
        "user1": true,
        "user2": true
    }
}

"messages":{
    "a151jl1j6":{}}
```

The part where this gets is little "inefficient" is the querying for conversations that include both user1 and user2. The recommended way is to create an index of conversations for each user and then query the `members` data.

```json
"user1":{
    "chats":{
        "a151jl1j6":true
    }
}
```

This is a trade-off when it comes to querying relationships with a flattened data structure. The queries are fast since you are only dealing with a subset of the data, but you end up with a lot of duplicate data that need to be accounted for when you are modifying/deleting i.e. when the user leaves the chat conversation, you have to update multiple structures.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So by this are you saying to check for an existing conversion with user x, I iterate through my chats and check each of them to see if user x is in them? This limits the query to the amount of chats I have, which should be inexpensive, right?

Comment: Yes, it also depends on the ux of your app; most chat apps have a screen displaying the list of all the chats so you'll already have the existing conversations locally in your app so you can even do the query locally since firebase will keep that synced up. However, if you expect people to start conversations from other places and need to check for existing conversations a lot, you can additionally index the conversations and its members in elastic search (https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) and perform more complex searches with just one query.

Answer (score 1):

I remember I had similar issue some time ago. The way how I solved it:

- user 1 has an unique ID `id1`
- user 2 has an unique ID `id2`

Instead of adding a new chat by autoId `chats/a151jl1j6` the ID of the chat was `id1---||---id2` *(superoriginal human-readable delimeter)*

*(which is exactly what you've originally suggested)*

> Originally, I put a reference to the other user as the value of the chatId key in the users/user/chats node, but I thought that was a bad idea in case I ever wanted group chats.

There is a saying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

There might a limitation of how many userIDs can live in the path - you can always hash the value...

Comment: So I guess my original thought was right. It makes sense having the user ids and the keys/values since it saves a query. Do you think this is scalable for group chats though? 

Other thoughts are, how do you know which order the user ids are in?

Comment: About the order - sorting to the rescue. About scaling to group chats - I've never needed such feature. YAGNI + always worth asking "what worst could happen" :)